# How can I create a development shell for qt 5.5 with debug symbols in the qt libraries

Tags: qt, nixos, nixpkgs

I have a development shell with a `buildInputs` entry that includes `qt55.qtbase`. This works great.

Today, I got a seg fault that happens in a qt library and I'd like qt libraries with debug symbols.

I took a look at `nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/qt-5/5.5/default.nix` and saw that it takes a parameter `developerBuild`.

I've introduced parameters into `buildInputs`of simple shells like this before with `callPackage`, but the construction of the qt packages is way over my head and I'm unable to produce a valid nix file for the shell.

How can I create a development shell for qt 5.5 software development that installs the qt libraries with debug symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `override` (see https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-pkg-override), so in your shell.nix/default.nix:

```
let qtBaseWithDebug = qt55.base.override { developerBuild = true; }; in
...
   buildInputs = [ ... qtBaseWithDebug ... ];
...
```

btw, you can see the parameters of packages at http://schmitthenner.eu/nixos-homepage/nixos/packages.html (although it's a little out of date currently)